# Почему у меня не открывается приложение скомпилированное в формат apk при импорте блютуза?

Tags: python, bluetooth, apk, kivy

Доброго времени суток.Вопрос заключается в следующем:Почему при компиляции кода на python у меня не высвечивается приложение на андроиде,но при этом я выяснил,что если убрать import bluetooth и все его составляющие,то оно будет работать?Имеется еще один вопрос,что надо сделать для работы блютуза на андроиде?
Вот сам код:

```js
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import bluetooth
class Widgets(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widgets, self).__init__()
 
    def btn_clk1(self):
        a = self.lbl.text 
        client=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
        ADDR = "00:68:58:00:6F:EA"
        client.connect((ADDR,1))
        client.send(a)
        client.close()
        
    def btn_clk2(self):
        server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
 
        port = 1
        server_sock.bind(("",port))
        server_sock.listen(1)
 
        client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
        print ("Accepted connection from ",address)
 
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        self.lbl.text = data
        client_sock.close()
        server_sock.close()
class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

```js
#File name: kivyn.py
#kivy 1.9.1
 
<Widgets>:
    lbl: my_label
    labe: my_labels
    Button:
        size: 100,75
        pos: 0,0
        text: "client"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        font_size: 40
        on_press: root.btn_clk1()
    Button:
        id: 1
        size: 170,75
        pos: 100,0
        text: "server"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
        on_press: root.btn_clk2()
    TextInput:
        id: my_label
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300,0
        text: ""
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
    TextInput:
        id: my_labels
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300,300
        text: "adr"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Что значит, 'у
меня не высвечивается
приложение на андроиде'? Модуль bleutooth, насколько я знаю, не входит в стандартную поставку Python, а это значит, что при сборке пакета для Android вы должны сказать все зависимости в android.requirements в файле  buildozer.spec. И вообще, когда вы уже научитесь читать логи?! В приложении на Kivy при его краше в корневой директории вашей программы в папке .kivy будет лог отчета.

Чтобы директория с вашим приложением после установки была на SD карте, и вы могли видеть логи, укажите в спецификации при сборке пакета - android.private_storage = False

Также не лишним будет, если вы в файле mаin.py при импорте основного класса приложения будете вести свой лог:

```
try:
    import program
except:
    # запись лога
```

Тогда вы будете задавать четкие вопросы, если хотите получить ответ, а так, извините, ни о чем!

Answer (score 0):

Извините,что так долго не писал.У меня появилась проблема,которая связана с компиляцией на виртуалке моего кода.Я вбил название модуля в buildozer.spec,но при этом появилась проблема:[image: это ошибка,которая высвечивается в терминале]

Подскажите,как мне ее исправить?